# How does Even Teams in NCAA Football 11 work?

Tags: ncaa-football-11

How, specifically, does the Even Teams feature work? I know it alters the overall level of each category of one team to match the other team, but it obviously doesn't match teams on a player to player basis (at least not as far as individual stats).

Also, are there any problems/exploits that are known to arise from the way the game evens the teams?